# Map substring without the help of libraries and without using regex

Tags: r, string, dictionary

I got a bunch of strings like

```
string_example="hi 5eme elephant 4eme dark I am"
```

I want to map those values

```
values_to_map=c("2eme","3eme","4eme","5eme")
```

to those ones

```
new_values=c("2e","3e","4e","5e")
```

Here is a solution that works great, but I found it a little tedious and I wonder if there is an easier way to do it **without the help from other libraries** (for some reasons, I need only to use RBase except the fastmatch library). I do not want to use regex as well because I got dozens of millions strings and it pretty slow.

```
library (fastmatch)
string_example="hi 5eme elephant 4eme dark I am"
string_example=str_split(string_example,pattern = " ")[[1]]
to_change=fmatch(string_example,values_to_map)

index=which(!is.na(to_change))
values=new_values[to_change[!is.na(to_change)]]
string_example[index]=values
```

Comment: “How to screw in a screw without using a screwdriver?” — Also known as: your requirements make no sense. (And regarding regex: have you checked that it’s actually slow? Regex *can* be implemented to be damn fast (on par with manual string processing), though many libraries unfortunately aren’t.)

Comment: It's prbly a homework assignment @KonradRudolph. There's no way a job wld create such restrictions.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Yeah: I was complaining about the course requirements, not about OP, who’s just in bad luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't grok the need for `fastmatch`:

```
`%||%` <- function (x, y) { if (is.na(x)) { y } else { x } }

string_example <- "hi 5eme elephant 4eme dark I am"
values_to_map <- c("2eme","3eme","4eme","5eme")
new_values <- c("2e","3e","4e","5e")
new_values <- setNames(new_values, values_to_map)

spl <- strsplit(string_example, " ")[[1]] 
spl <- unname(sapply(spl, function(x) {
  new_values[x] %||% x
})) 
spl <- paste0(spl, collapse=" ")
spl
## [1] "hi 5e elephant 4e dark I am"
```

This is pretty fragile and makes quite a number of assumptions, mostly due to a very vague question with inane requirements. If it's homework, point your instructor here so they can see just how poor their instructing is.

This:

```
vapply(string_example, function(spl) {
  spl <- strsplit(spl, " ")[[1]] 
  spl <- unname(vapply(spl, function(x) {
    new_values[x] %||% x
  }, character(1))) 
  paste0(spl, collapse=" ")
}, character(1), USE.NAMES=FALSE)
```

will be marginally faster and work over a character vector.

Comment: Waouh, impressive! Do not get what you talked about (instructor, etc.) though. Thks!Did not know unname!

Comment: Yep. Python is an abomination.

Comment: Are you sarcastic? Why do you say that?

Comment: It is. Fragmented. Verbose. Inconsistent (far more than R is). Plus SO wldnt let me respond with just "yep"